# Anonymous arguments in julia

Tags: julia

Julia permits function and method definitions with unnamed arguments.

This is not mentioned in the [functions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/index.html) documentation, nor is it explicitly discussed in the [methods](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/) documentation. For example:

```
function myfunc(::Int)
    println("Hello!")
end
```

How should I describe this behavior (I've googled "anonymous arguments" without success), and when is it useful?

Comment: I've googled "anonymous arguments" and found this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is useful for method dispatch, when you care only about argument type not argument value. Most often this is a case when what you dispatch on is a singleton type.

An example is:

```
julia> Vector{String}(undef, 3)
3-element Array{String,1}:
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
```

This function is defined in the following way:

```
Array{T,1}(::UndefInitializer, m::Int) where {T} =
    ccall(:jl_alloc_array_1d, Array{T,1}, (Any, Int), Array{T,1}, m)
```

And you can see that we only care that the first argument was of `UndefInitializer` type, which is in turn defined as:

```
struct UndefInitializer end
const undef = UndefInitializer()
```

We see that `UndefInitializer` is a singleton type, so we do not care about the value of a variable of this type, but only about its type.

Another common singleton type in Base is `Missing`. Here are example definitions from Base of standard functions getting a `Missing` as an argument:

```
for f in (:(acos), :(acosh), :(asin), :(asinh), :(atan), :(atanh),
          :(sin), :(sinh), :(cos), :(cosh), :(tan), :(tanh),
          :(exp), :(exp2), :(expm1), :(log), :(log10), :(log1p),
          :(log2), :(exponent), :(sqrt))
    @eval $(f)(::Missing) = missing
end
```

(again - you can see that we do not care about the value of the variable - we know its type is `Missing` so we return `missing`)

In the Julia manual you have examples of such methods e.g. [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/methods/#Extracting-the-type-parameter-from-a-super-type-1) but admittedly as far as I can tell the manual does not give a name for this style of method definition.

Comment: Even in the base library, the functionality is not always utilized.  For example the length of a number is defined with `length(x::Number) = 1`, where the variable `x` is not used.